# How to provide list of features when creating Spartacus project programmatically (interactive=false)

Tags: spartacus-storefront

when creating a new SAP Spartacus project with Schematics in a programmatically way (`interactive=false`)

```
ng add @spartacus/schematics@latest --skip-confirmation --interactive=false --base-url https://${FQDN} --pwa --base-site=powertools-spa --currency=usd --language=en,de --ssr
```

would it be possible to pass over the list of features to be enabled, different from the ones pre-defined in [schema.json#L52](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/schematics/src/add-spartacus/schema.json#L52)?

```
  "default": [
    "ASM",
    "Cart",
    "WishList",
    "Checkout",
    "Order",
    "Import-Export",
    "Saved-Cart",
    "Quick-Order",
    "Image-Zoom",
    "Product-Variants",
    "SmartEdit",
    "Store-Finder",
    "Personalization",
    "User-Account",
    "User-Profile"
  ]
```

This is to avoid the need to manually install the additional features one by one:

```
ng add @spartacus/organization --skip-confirmation
ng add @spartacus/product-configurator --features="VC-Configurator" --skip-confirmation
```

List of available features from [schema.json#L18](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/schematics/src/add-spartacus/schema.json#L18):

```
    "enum": [
      "ASM",
      "Import-Export",
      "Saved-Cart",
      "Quick-Order",
      "CDC",
      "CDS",
      "Cart",
      "WishList",
      "Checkout",
      "Checkout-B2B",
      "Checkout-Scheduled-Replenishment",
      "Order",
      "Digital-Payments",
      "EPD-Visualization",
      "Administration",
      "Order-Approval",
      "Bulk-Pricing",
      "Image-Zoom",
      "Product-Variants",
      "VC-Configurator",
      "Textfield-Configurator",
      "CPQ-Configurator",
      "Qualtrics",
      "SmartEdit",
      "Store-Finder",
      "Personalization",
      "TMS-GTM",
      "TMS-AEPL",
      "User-Account",
      "User-Profile"
    ],
```

thanks
nicola

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to do it.
You can append multiple `features` options, like so: `ng add @spartacus/schematics .... --features=feature1 --features=feature2 ... --features=featureN`.

Comment: thanks @pegasus I tried with `ng add @spartacus/schematics@latest --skip-confirmation --interactive=false --base-url https://${FQDN} --pwa --base-site=powertools-spa --currency=usd --language=en,de --features=Administration --features=VC-Configurator --features=Order-Approval` to replicate the 2 `ng add` above but it didn't get to the same output? Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "didn't get to the same output"? Maybe you can provide more details?

Comment: thanks @pegasus I would have expected to have the same set of extensions. As an example, running with the one-liner above the `@spartacus/user` was not added, making the store unusable. I assume some kind of transitive dependency was not picked up?

Comment: Not working anymore with Spartacus 5.x - `ng add @spartacus/product-configurator --features="VC-Configurator" --skip-confirmation` - @nikola-zarić any hint? tried with `ng add @spartacus/product-configurator --features=["VC-Configurator"] --skip-confirmation` as well, always leading to `Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"features":"[VC-Configurator]","project":"b2bstore"}`